# Maps and substrings

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I want to sort suffices of a string. 
The most simple way to do that is putting all the suffices into map.
In order to use memory efficiently, I pass suffix as (str+i), where str is char* and i is a position suffix starts with. However, I found out that map is not going to sort these suffices. Here goes an example

```
typedef std::map < char*, int,Comparator> MapType;
MapType data;

// let's declare some initial values to this map
char* bob=(char* )"Bobs score";
char* marty=(char* ) "Martys score";
data.insert(pair<char*,int>(marty+1,15));
data.insert(pair<char*,int>(bob+1,10));
MapType::iterator end = data.end();
for (MapType::iterator it = data.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << "Who(key = first): " << it->first;
    std::cout << " Score(value = second): " << it->second << '\n';
}
```

The output is

```
    Who(key = first): obs score Score(value = second): 10
    Who(key = first): artys score Score(value = second): 15
```

However, `strcmp`, standard function for comparing strings, works correctly for bob+1 and marty+1. It says marty+1 is less than bob+1.

Comment: Where is `Comparator` defined and what it does?

Comment: of course the Comparator is wrong with respect to how the map is defined (`char *`, int)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `map` will sort by the address of the `char*`, not lexiographically. Change the key to a `std::string` or define a comparator.

EDIT:

It looks as though you have attempted to define a `Comparator` but the definition of it is not posted. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>

struct cstring_compare
{
    bool operator()(const char* a_1, const char* a_2) const
    {
        return strcmp(a_1, a_2) < 0;
    }
};

typedef std::map<const char*, int, cstring_compare> cstring_map;

int main()
{
    cstring_map m;

    m["bcd"] = 1;
    m["acd"] = 1;
    m["abc"] = 1;

    for (cstring_map::iterator i =  m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i->first << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
acd
bcd
```

Comment: or change the comparator you use

Comment: @ShinTakezou, yep. Think the OP might have already tried to though.

Comment: missing the include cstring for strcmp

Comment: @ShinTakezou, i was just adding it!

Answer (score 0):

define a custom Comparator, eg

```
class compare_char { 
   public:
      bool operator()(const char* lhs, const char* rhs) { return strcmp(lhs, rhs); } 
};
```

define your map using this comparator instead of whatever you currently have. Alternatively, use a map with a key type that has a comparison operator that works with values, a std::string is better for you. Currently you have a map using char* as the key which compares char* types, ie. the value of the pointer, not the contents.

Comment: I suspect this could not work, since strcmp returns non-zero (true) in both cases when lhs is greater or lesser than rhs; you should add `< 0` (as in the hmjd answer)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the comparer class or function you are using since that is where your error is probably coming from. 
There is a slight difference between strcmp and a map comparaison function.

strcmp returns 0 if a == b, -1 if a < b, 1 if a > b
comp returns true is a < b, false otherwise.

A correct way to implement the comparison function is the following:

```
bool operator() (char* lhs, char* rhs) const
{
        return strcmp(lhs,rhs) < 0;
}
```